# Universe execute a Linux command from within a Basic program

Tags: linux, universe

Am attempting to execute an `ls -al` from within a Universe basic program and it isn't working as expected.

```
EXECUTE 'sh'
EXECUTE 'ls -al | grep FILELIST'
```

The program is shelling out to Linux, but then stops prior to execution of the `ls` command. Anyone have any ideas of how to get around this one?

Comment: I have no idea about universe basic but I highly doubt you want to use EXECUTE twice in one statement.

Comment: Actually n.m yes in Universe it's quite normal to execute a number of times depending on requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
COMANDA = "ls -al | grep FILELIST"
EXECUTE "sh -c '":COMANDA:"'" CAPTURING DADES
CRT DADES
```

it work at SunOS.

Comment: This would require that you have an entry for SH in your VOC, which I think it pretty common (if not standard).